# Deserialize Interface objects FireStore Android

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

i have a general interface like this:

```
interface MyInterface {
    val param1: String
    val param2: String
    ...
}
```

Which can be transalted in objects of different types (3 in total).

I'm using Firestore to save a myDocument object which contains among other params, a list of myInterface objects but obviously it can't be serialized because interfaces doesn't have a general constructor.

I also can't avoid having such list inside myDocument. Is there a way i can use to save myDocument even if it contains a list of interface onbjects?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using an interface and not a data class?